# Road bike rentals in Europe

Tags: road-bike

I'm going on a holiday to Southern France for road cycling within the Provence region and I'm wondering if I shell out on a bike box and take my own bike or just hire a road bike out there. Does anyone go on holiday and rent?

If you have been and had an unpleasant experience with the rental could you say what happened?

Comment: This depends a lot on where you are. If you're flying from the US for example, taking your own bike is probably pretty expensive.

Comment: Spinlister maybe?

Comment: Personally, I just wouldn't feel comfortable riding a bike that I hadn't given a complete maintenance myself.

Comment: I'm voting to close until there is more detail, such as where you are travelling from, and what riding you intend to do there. People do hire bikes there and give good reports. Haven't heard any horror stories.

Comment: I can't personally vouch for them, but francebikerentals.com is a thing that exists.